# VBA Array Return the Number not the String

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have created an array as range of cells that contains numbers and text. One column is called `PolicyNumber`. There are values as:

```
11/2007
8/2006
12/2005
etc.
```

If I want to copy the cells from the array back to the sheet it returns not values `11/2007`, `8/2006`, `12/2005`, etc, however it returns the result of calculation

```
11/2007 = 0.00548
8/2006 = 0.003988
12/2005 = 0.00598
etc.
```

I have tried

1. Formatted the values `PolicyNumber`as text before created the array;
2. Split the `PolicyNumber` onto two cells and than put them back;
3. When exported the values from the array used function format, cstr.

I hope that it is clear to understand the problem.

Comment: How are you pasting the values into the worksheet? You need to show  your **code**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the policynumber column is formatted as text, then formatting the output as text works for me:

```
Sub getit()
    Dim var As Variant
    var = Range("a1:A2")
    Range("c1:c2").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("c1:c2") = var
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub firstcheck()

Dim X()
dim ind as Worksheet, FC as Worksheet
dim N as Double 

Set ind = Sheets("Input Data")

Set FC - Sheets("First Check")
N = Application.CountA(Ind.Range("G:G"))

X = ind.Range("C2:T" & N).Value 'data
....
FC.Range("B2:S" & N) = X

End Sub
```

Column :

Policynumber:

Data that works ok :

```
99-155547/003
99-155690/003
99-155837/003
99-173341/003
99-185326/003
```

Copied some data that does not work:

```
2013/00176
2012/08233
2012/08016
2012/08330
2012/08749
2012/01122
```